# Get event viewer logs with win api in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, event-log, event-viewer

My application need to save event viewer logs to a specified directory and it has to be done with win api. Application and System logs are required.

EDIT: EvtExportLog - I found out that I can't use this function because minimal requirements are Win Server 2008, and I need this to work on Win Server 2000 and Win Server 2003.

Any suggestions what to use and how to use it?

And there is solution thanks to Richard Cook.

```
    int getEventLogs()
{
    HANDLE h = OpenEventLog(NULL,"System");
    if(!BackupEventLog(h,"backup.evt"))
    {
        wprintf(L"BackupEventLog failed for initial export with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate the available channels on the system using `EvtOpenChannelEnum`, `EvtNextChannelPath` and `EvtClose` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385437(v=VS.85).aspx)). These APIs (`EvtNextChannelPath` specifically) will return paths in an appropriate format for `EvtExportLog`.

Comment: tnx for quick reply, but i found out that requirements for these functions are win server 2008, and I need this to work on win server 2000 and 2003. Any suggestions?

Comment: The documentation for the older APIs (Windows 2000, XP and Windows Server 2003) is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652(v=VS.85).aspx. `BackupEventLog` is probably what you need.

Comment: Anyway to read/backup eventlogs in a particular date/time range , say from Jan 1 to Jan 7?